# How to use css animate correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

How to use animation.css correctly? I use it this way:
    .

```
animated {
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
-ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
-o-animation-fill-mode:both;
animation-fill-mode:both;

-webkit-animation-duration:1.5s;
-moz-animation-duration:1.5s;
-ms-animation-duration:1.5s;
-o-animation-duration:1.5s;
animation-duration:1.5s;
}

.animated.hinge{
-webkit-animation-duration:1.5s;
-moz-animation-duration:1.5s;
-ms-animation-duration:1.5s;
-o-animation-duration:1.5s;
animation-duration:1.5s;
}


@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {opacity: 0;}    
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {opacity: 0;}    
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {opacity: 0;}    
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}

.fadeIn {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeIn;
    -o-animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
```

I call this animated by clicking on a link. So, the content should like fadeIn on my page, so that the user has something nice to watch till the content is there. I call this animated classes by a jQuery function in an onclick-event. This function looks like this:

```
  function getRightCol(){
               $('#right-col').addClass('fadeIn animated').removeClass('hidden');
                       window.setTimeout( function(){
                                   $('#right-col').addClass('shown fadeIn');},1000);
                            window.setTimeout( function(){
              $('#right-col').removeClass('fadeIn fadeOut animated');},1000);                         
    };
```

The point is, Firefox does this animation perfectly. Chrome and Safari don't do anything except showing the content instantly. Furthermore i have the script in the bottom of my html page. If you want to look the page and its look at the moment check: wp.cloudstarter.de 
So, why doesn't it work on Chrome? Where is my mistake? I would also appreciate general tips for using css-animations.

EDIT: Yeah, i am a Newbie.

Comment: I copied the css-classes from https://daneden.me/animate/

Comment: You can always try add this, it's only few lines ;) It's look like missing -webkit, nothing more.

Comment: Oh damn. Thats right, problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this to your css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {opacity:0;}
100%  {opacity:1;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {opacity: 0;}    
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```